# How should I switch a person to another team in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So let's say I have 2 teams, Winner and Player. When a player is the only one left on Player, I want to add them/switch them to Winner and remove them from Player. I already have all the testing for figuring out how many players there are on a team, but I still need the command for switching the players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To switch a person still on the Player team to the Winner team:

```
/scoreboard teams join Winner @a[team=Player]
```

You can only be in one team at once, so this will also automatically remove them from the Player team.

Comment: *Any* person on the `Player` team will be switched to the `Winner` team, not just *a* person.

Comment: @sharpturn It'll only switch one person if OP has it set up as they say they have (though the command does have the ability to switch more people if the Player team has more than one person left).

Comment: Ah, yes, I suppose so. I just normally use `@p` when switching one player. The word "the" used to describe an `@a` command with no count target selector var just the me off a bit. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @sharpturn `@p` doesn't select dead players, so may not always move the player from the `Player` team to the `Winner` team.

Comment: Ah. And I suppose. `@a[c=1]` would be kind of pointless here.

Comment: @sharpturn Yeah, if OP's current setup works.

Comment: It does, don't worry lol